# getting an image path from a imageview?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an `ImageView` and I want get the path of image and add in a `String`. I want do this because I need send this to my webservice like a default image

How can I do it ?

**ImageView**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivPerfil"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_usuario"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    />
```

**Getting the path**

```
ivPerfil = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivPerfil);
Drawable img = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_usuario);
String pathImage = img.toString();
```

Comment: So what is `pathImage` if not the path, to the image, as requested?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.name/" + R.drawable.icon_usuario);
    String imgPath = path.toString();
```

"your.package.name" is the name of your package (i.e: com.example.mypackage)

You can use this path in android like this:

```
ivPerfil = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivPerfil);
ivPerfil.setImageURI(path);
```

Answer (score 11):

You can't directly get the path to the image referenced by the `ImageView`, but there is a bit of a way around it.

Since you clearly know the path to the image when setting it (since you wouldn't be able to set it without knowing it), you have the option to set the `View's` tag (which can technically be any `Object`).

In this case, it's just a `String` you're going to want to store.

So let's say you have:

```
Uri imageFilePath = Uri.parse("some/path/to/file.png");
```

Now, when setting the image Uri on the `ImageView`, add this after to set its tag:

```
imageView.setTag(imageFilePath.toString());
```

Then, when you're actually going to send it to the server, just call the `getTag()` method on your `ImageView` and you'll get the correct file location.

e.g.

```
String path = imageView.getTag().toString();
```

If the image is from your assets, though, you're going to have to construct the appropriate path from the resources (see miselking's answer on this page for how to do that).