# Can I get the src URI from an Imageview?

Tags: android, imageview, src

is it possible to get the src Value of an ImageView as URI?

Help would be great

Comment: Do you want to get this on runtime?

Answer (score 1):

No. By the time the `ImageView` has the image, the source of that image is long gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what image it is in your drawable, you can do something like this.

```
String path = Uri.parse("android.resource://my.package.name/" + R.drawable.myimage).toString();
```

More info - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28505621/2197529